# Lenovo Legion 5 Ubuntu installation error

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo Legion 5. When I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04, it showed the following error message with the screen stuck.

[image: Picture of screen showing error]

I tried again with disabling Secure Boot, but still no response.

How can I install Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 was released three years before your hardware (early 2021), so your compatibility problem does not seem surprising. Try a pre-release Ubuntu 21.10. It will be released next week. It has the best likelihood of compatibility with your new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, try the second option (ubuntu (safe graphic)) in the previous menu